# MySql - updating 2 columns simultaneously from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One table is a list of all the possible unique values for column1 with 2 other columns of data.

The second table has 3 columns with the same values from column1 but repeated multiple times.

I have a query that works to copy columns 2 and 3 from TableA to TableB, but it takes forever to run. This is what I have:

```
    TableA
    column1 column2 column3
    1       1       1
    2       2       2

    TableB
    column1 column2 column3
    1       a       b
    2       c       d
    3       e       f
```

```
update TableA
set column2 = (
    select column2
    from TableB
    where TableA.column1 = TableB.column1
);

update TableA
set column3 = (
    select column3
    from TableB
    where TableA.column1 = TableB.column1
);
```

I tried to do it by using a JOIN, but that actually takes even longer.....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an `INNER JOIN` query this way

```
UPDATE tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b
ON a.column1 = b.column1
SET b.column2 = a.column2,
    b.column3 = a.column3
```

If there are so many records it will take some times though

Comment: There are a lot of records, so it takes close to an hour - is there no quicker way?

Comment: I don't think so, anyway you can use this and then set a trigger everytime that something change in table1 change it on tableb according

Comment: `is there no quicker way?` ... if you setup indices on the join columns then it should be relatively fast.

Comment: Apparently, I can't upvote this, but its excellent, it has reduced it to less than 3 minutes!!!! Thank you